# "Entry point DPAlInit could not be located in dll" error in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2017, digital-persona-sdk

I downloaded and run a C++ project for [Digital-persona-sdk finger print](https://github.com/iamonuwa/Digital-Persona-SDK/archive/refs/heads/master.zip). I run the environment in Visual Studio (Windows 10 64-bit). Compilation is done, but when I run the exe, this problem occurs:

[image: Digital persona project vs 2017]

Does anyone have an idea for solving this problem? Or, can you please give me any other sample project for working with the Digital persona fingerprint sdk in C++?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0):

I find out the problem. It problem is my project has a window application. But i run the console application and select win32.